# GQL nodejs library get(keys) return key name in results

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gql

I'm currently performing a batch GQL query using the NodeJS datastore library with a list of keys.

```
datastore.get(keys).then((results) => {
// Tasks retrieved successfully.
console.log("results", JSON.stringify(results));

res.send()
});
```

for instance if my keys have ids of 1,2,3,4

when get my results I'd like something such as

```
   [ {1: {key:value}}, {2: {key:value}},{3: {key:value}},{4: {key:value}}]
```

whereas at the moment I just get

```
   [ {key:value}, {key:value},{key:value},{key:value}]
```

The results are all returned successfully, but the ids are not returned with the results. Is there anyway to retrieve the id as part of the results so I know what results match what id as visually they don't appear to be in the order of the keys passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to get the key I just needed to get a specific entity from my `results` object and get the [datastore.KEY] property

e.g

```
 let entity = results[0];
 let key = entity[datastore.KEY];
```

where `datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')();`

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1724